# creating a plan guide

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

On SQL Server, I am testing to create a Plan guide to force a query from Java to use a specific optimal execution-plan always. Some how the SQL query not using this Plan Guide

I followed, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190772%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

SQL comes from Java,

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=1986
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P0 nvarchar(4000)',N'SELECT Top 1 Amount,col2 from dbo.table1
                                                                                 where ExId=@P0
                                                                                 order by id
                                                 ',N'0a8e8e31-2a05-0000-8ece-0003fd69e692'
select @p1
```

Plan Guide I created,

```
DECLARE @xml_showplan nvarchar(max);
SET @xml_showplan = (select cast(query_plan as nvarchar(max))  from sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text (cp.plan_handle) st 
cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan (cp.plan_handle) qp 
where st.text like '%Top 1 Amount%'
and objtype='Prepared')

--select (@xml_showplan)



EXEC sp_create_plan_guide
@name = N'ForceuserLoanAmountRequests',
@stmt = N'SELECT Top 1 Amount,col2 from dbo.table1 where ExId=@P0 order by id', 
@type = N'SQL',
@module_or_batch = NULL,
@params = N'@P0 nvarchar(4000)',
@hints = @xml_showplan;
```

Appreciate if you can help me to get thru the plan guide used by SQL query from java.

Created a Plan Guide with the SQL collected from SQL Profiler,

```
EXEC sp_create_plan_guide
@name = N'ForceuserLoanAmountRequests',
@stmt = N'SELECT Top 1 Amount,col2 from table1
                                                                                 where ExId=@P0
                                                                                 order by ID
                                                 ',
@type = N'SQL',
@module_or_batch = NULL,
@params = N'@P0 nvarchar(4000)',
@hints = @xml_showplan;

GO
```

Comment: I ran a trace by using SQL Server Profiler and select the events Plan Guide Successful and **Plan Guide Unsuccessful** from the Performance category, to check whether this SQL from Java code uses the plan guide or not and these events never fired every time this SQL executed

Answer (score 2):

Please read the article [sp_create_plan_guide (Transact-SQL)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179880(v=sql.105).aspx) pay attention to Remarks:

> Plan Guide Matching Requirements
>
> For plan guides that specify @type = 'SQL' or @type = 'TEMPLATE' to
>   successfully match a query, the values for batch_text and
>   @parameter_name data_type [,...n ] **must be provided in exactly the
>   same format as their counterparts submitted by the application.** This
>   means you must provide the batch text exactly as the SQL Server
>   compiler receives it. To capture the actual batch and parameter text,
>   you can use SQL Server Profiler. For more information, see Using SQL
>   Server Profiler to Create and Test Plan Guides.

This means that the statement should **exactly** match to what is written in your `plan guide`, but in your code plan guide is created for a statement that differs from those sending by java: it has only one row while `java` code has 4 rows with `CR` and additional spaces.

If you evaluate any hash from `java` statement and your statement provided in `sp_create_plan_guide` you'll see they are different.

Another thing I suspect that may be wrong is how you get a "good plan". Since you just assign `@xml_showplan` the result of a query that can produce many rows, I'm not sure you get the plan you want. How do you ensure that you capture the "good£ plan and not the same plan that java code produced?

Comment: I did try creating with SQL Statement exactly match with Java passes to SQL Server, collected thru Profiler. PFA for my original question. Also to your question "good plan" , currently this query using optimal plan, and so collected that plan to **@xml_showplan**

Comment: Sorry, there is one thing I cannot understand. You said: "currently this query using optimal plan", so WHY do you think that it does not use plan guide?

Comment: I think I am not very clear with initial problem statement. Let me try to clear that, the query some times run efficiently uses a correct plan and over time when cache cleared, it gets non optimal plan. I know we should update stats for this kind of issue. However since its a Dev environment, no maintenance tasks. So to address this, I create a Plan guide when the query runs with optimal execution plan and when ever it gets a sub optimal plan for any reason, I expect it to use a Optimal exec plan thru a Plan Guide. Hope I am clear now and let me know if have doubts. Happy to answer

Comment: Your query has a parameter, so your problem is **parameter sniffing**. I mean, for different parameter different plan can be built. When the cache is cleared, the plan is built for the parameter that arrives at the **first** execution. If it is typical parameter, you call the plan optimal because it suits for most possible cases, if parameter is atypical, the plan that was good for this parameter will be used for other parameters too and that is what you want to prevent. You can add **recompile** option to your code or **optimize for (@P0=...)** option to always get optimal plan

Comment: **recompile** for every execution is not good as this SQL runs very frequently and also with a query hint, **Optimize for** you are restricting to one parameter. Actually in this case , we should use **Optimize for None** . Either way this required Code change. I can address all these with *Plan Guide* enforcing a optimal plan